# does putting Linq query inside a method affect deferred excecution?

Tags: c#, linq, deferred-execution

Linq query is not executed until the sequence returned by the query is actually iterated.

I have a query that is used repeatedly, so I am going to encapuslate it inside a method. I'd like to know if it interferes with the deferred execution.
If I encapsulate a Linq query into a method like below,
the query gets executed at line 2, not line 1 where the method is called. Is this correct?

```
public IEnumerable<Person> GetOldPeopleQuery()
{
   return personList.Where(p => p.Age > 60);
}

public void SomeOtherMethod()
{
   var getWomenQuery = GetOldPeopleQuery().Where(p => p.Gender == "F"); //line 1
   int numberOfOldWomen = getWomanQuery.Count();  //line 2
}
```

P.S. I am using Linq-To-EF, if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is lazy evaluated when you enumerate the result the first time, that is not affected by putting it inside a method.

There is however another thing in your code that will be very inefficient. Once you've returned an `IEnumerable` the next linq statement applied to the collection will be a linq-to-objects query. That means that in your case you will load *all* old people from the database and then filter out the women in memory. The same with the count, it will be done in memory.

If you instead return an `IQueryable<Person>` those two questions will be evaluated using linq-to-entities and the filtering and summing can be done in the database.

Comment: There's no indication in this question that a database is actually involved. But if it is, I agree with you about the inefficiency.

Comment: Thank you! so I'll be using IQueryable<T> instead.